# Safari extension settings

Tags: jquery, message, safari-extension

I'm building a safari extension... I need to get some settings, but, messages are asynchronous, so, if I query the global page for some settings, it isn't there right away... How can I solve this??

Global page (the message is received by the injected JS script)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
  <script language="javascript">
  function messageHandler(event) {
   var activeTab = event.target.browserWindow.activeTab
   if (event.name === "getSettings") {
    activeTab.page.dispatchMessage("returnedSettings", safari.extension.settings[event.message]);
   } else if(event.name === 'openNewTab') {
    safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab().url = event.message;
    activeTab.page.dispatchMessage("focus");
   } else if(event.name === 'openNewVenster') {
    safari.application.openBrowserWindow().activeTab.url = event.message;
    //activeTab.page.dispatchMessage("focus");
   }
  }

  safari.application.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);
  </script>
 </head>
    </html>
```

main.js

```
        var oi = 'tab';
  // Message Event Handler
  function handleMessage(e) {
   if(e.name == 'returnedSettings') {
    oi = e.message;
   } else if(e.name == 'focus') {
    window.focus();
   }
  }

  // Message Event Listener
  safari.self.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
  safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('getSettings', 'open');
```

I need `var oi` in code under here... But I don't know how I can get it there, because it will be default if the code is executed, because of asynchronous messages...

Comment: thanks for editing the code ;) I am still not used to the way how code is presented here...

Comment: I changed the way my script in the injected.js works, it calls a function when the message is received...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say much about what you're trying to do, but you're right that messages are asynchronous. If what you're doing can't be done directly in the global page, you can use the specialized `canLoad` message. It's kind of a hack unless, of course, you're actually checking to see whether something can load, but I've used it a few times rather effectively.